# Which Data Structure is Best to represent a Three-Player Chess Board?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hashmap, graph-theory

[image]

I'm trying to start coding three-player chess and am at the stage of brainstorming possible implementations.
I am completely stuck on how to best represent this board in a way that can be easily traversed. A typical chess board is easy enough to use a simple x and y position for each square. You can use that to calculate valid moves for each piece with a little arithmetic.

This is very different to me, as you can't simply increment/decrement each rank and file by one to find a given adjacent square.

I've considered using a graph with each node being a square and each edge representing an adjacency, and this would work, but I'm not sure how you could use that to traverse the graph effectively when determining the board state, checking valid positions and move, etc.

Link to the website demonstrating the rules regarding each piece: https://greenchess.net/rules.php?v=three-player

UPDATE: Last night, I went ahead and implemented a graph theory model and I think this may work well enough.

[image: Graph Theory Representation]

Using NetworkX, I was able to build a graph where each node has a unique rank and file based on the board in the top image. I was then able to construct the orthogonal and diagonal edges. In order to move pieces on the board, a function can grab all neighbors and check the rank and file attributes of each node to determine the direction the piece is attempting to move in. Ex: a piece at B3 is orthogonally adjacent to B2, B4, A3, and C3. This means that orthogonal spaces always share exactly one attribute. Diagonal neighbors will share no attributes, so in this example of starting position B3, diagonal neighbors would be A2, A4, C2, and C4.

Knights would need to check for all neighbors of neighbors that don't have the starting position as a neighbor, don't share a rank or file with the starting position, and are of the opposite color of the starting position.

Pawns might be a little tricky, but I think I have a good start and can likely iron out how those pieces can select a valid destination with some time to think about it.

Comment: The language isn't super important, but I was going to attempt in python for simplicity. I will look into graph libraries. Thank you.

Comment: You would need a new notation for representing three sets of pieces (upper lower can only cover two). And I'm honestly not sure at all how you represent the additional four ranks and files. Each player shares half of it's board with a different opponent.

Comment: The lettering/numbering of the squares in your picture suggests using a 12x12 grid where only 96 of the 144 squares can every actually be used/reached.

Comment: Here is my suggestion for Chess3 FEN format rules https://github.com/JamesBremner/chess/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards-Notation#chess3

Comment: @ChrisDodd  Clever thought.  However, storing the adjacencies in a graph data structure captures all is needed about the underlying geometry

Comment: I'm still not sure which language to use. I'm open to see how others implement their chess engines for ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already suggested, the board has essentially 4 rows of 8 squares in front of each of the three players. We can call such 4 x 8 group of cells a "group". A square can be identified by its group index (0, 1 or 2), row index (0..3) and column index (0..7).

Setting up the links between cells can be analysed as follows:

- Vertical and horizontal adjacency: nothing special. A square has at most 4 such neighbors, like on a standard chess board.
- Diagonal adjacency: a diagonal step can be seen as a combination of a horizontal and vertical step. Sometimes the *order* in which these two steps are performed can make a difference. This is the case for the center squares.

Here is an implementation in Python where these links are set up dynamically and/or retrieved at runtime:

```py
class Square:
    opposite = {"N": "S", "E": "W", "S": "N", "W": "E"}
    def __init__(self, name, side, down, left):
        # side: Player: Each player has 4 rows of squares in front of them. Side identifies which of
        #    those three groups has this square.
        #    A group's 4 rows are numbered from 0 (nearest to player) to 3 (away from player),
        #    and its 8 half-columns are numbered from left to right from the player's viewpoint.
        # down and left allow to immediately link with neighbors
        self.name = name
        self.side = side
        # neighbor references (using direction names as from the closest player's point of view)
        self.N = self.E = None
        self.S = down or None
        self.W = left or None
        # set backreferences
        if down:
            down.N = self
        if left:
            left.E = self
            
    def walk(self, path, reverse=False):  # Yield square(s) at end of relative path
        # Path: string of one or more N, E, S, W (from square's side point of view)
        # Could yield 2 squares if with the reversed order of the directions we arrive at a different square
        prev = None
        for curpath in [path] if path[::-1] == path else [path, path[::-1]]:
            square = self
            curreverse = reverse
            for step in curpath:
                player = square.side
                square = getattr(square, self.opposite[step] if curreverse else step)
                if not square or square is prev:
                    return  # Outside board or same square as in previous iteration
                if square.side != player:
                    curreverse = not curreverse  # Crossed over to different half-board
            yield square, curreverse
            prev = square
        
    # Given constraints about movement, generate target squares that can be reached from this square. 
    def targets(self, player, directions, limit=10):
        reverse = player != self.side  # Whether or not directions should be mirrored
        stack = [(self, reverse, path, limit) for path in directions]
        while stack:  # While there are squares to further expand
            square, reverse, path, limit = stack.pop()
            for square, reverse in square.walk(path, reverse):
                yield square
                if limit > 1:  # Continue in the same direction
                    stack.append((square, reverse, path, limit - 1))

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

class Player:
    def __init__(self, color, colnames, rownames, next=None):
        self.color = color
        self.next = next or self
        # Create the half-board at the side of this player
        squares = []
        for row, rowname in enumerate(rownames):
            for column, colname in enumerate(colnames):
                square = Square(f"{colname}{rowname}", self, row and squares[-8], column and squares[-1])
                squares.append(square)
        self.squares = squares
        
    def __iter__(self):  # iterate over linked list of players, including self
        side = self
        while True:
            yield side
            side = side.next
            if side == self:
                break
        
    def add(self, color, colnames, rownames):
        self.next = Player(color, colnames, rownames, self.next)
        # Link cross-group neighbors
        for player in (self, self.next):
            for sq1, sq2 in zip(player.next.squares[:-5:-1], player.squares[-8:]):
                sq1.N = sq2
                sq2.N = sq1
        return self.next

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.color

        
class ThreePlayerChess:
    def __init__(self):
        # Create a linked list of 3 players, each with their half-board of squares
        self.players = { player.color.lower(): player 
                        for player in Player("Red",   "abcdefgh", "1234")
                                        .add("White", "lkjidcba", "8765")
                                        .add("Black", "hgfeijkl", ("12","11","10", "9")).next }
        # Make squares accessible by their names
        self.squaresbyname = { square.name : square
                                for player in self.players.values()
                                for square in player.squares }
        self.player = self.players["white"]


game = ThreePlayerChess()
# One step from d5 in North-West direction from White's point of view (two results!):
print(*game.squaresbyname["d5"].targets(game.players["white"], ("NW", ), 1))
# -> e4 i9
# All Bishop moves from d5:
print(*game.squaresbyname["d5"].targets(game.players["white"], ("NW", "NE", "SE", "SW"), 10))
# -> i6 j7 k8 c6 b7 a8 c4 b3 a2 e4 i9 j10 k11 l12 f3 g2 h1
# All knight moves from d5:
print(*game.squaresbyname["d5"].targets(game.players["white"], ("NNE", "NEE", "SEE", "SSE", "SSW", "SWW", "NWW", "NNW"), 1))
# -> e3 i10 f4 j9 j6 i7 c7 b6 b4 c3
```

The idea here is to express a desired *direction* using North-East-South-West indications, to be interpreted from the viewpoint of the current player.

So for instance, when player White has a bishop on square d5 and wants to make one step in North-West direction (from their viewpoint), we can end up on square i9 or e4. The above code runs that as a test. The output is `e4 i9`.

The second output lists all possible target squares for a bishop that is positioned on d5: there are 17 of them:

```
i6 j7 k8 c6 b7 a8 c4 b3 a2 e4 i9 j10 k11 l12 f3 g2 h1
```

The third output lists all possible target squares for a knight that is positioned on d5: there are 10 of them:

```
e3 i10 f4 j9 j6 i7 c7 b6 b4 c3
```

#### Adding the pieces...

The above created data structure is ready to be used by actual piece movements. Below I introduced a `Piece` class and subclasses for each type of piece, added a `startposition` method that sets up the initial board, and added functions to produce all possible moves, including castling, promotion and *en passant* captures:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
import re

class Piece:
    def __init__(self, owner, movecount=0):
        self.owner = owner  # Player
        self.square = None
        self.movecount = movecount
        
    def placeat(self, square, addmovecount=0):
        if square and square.piece:
            square.piece.remove()  # Capture the piece that is on the given square
        if self.square:
            self.square.piece = None  # Clear the square where this piece comes from
        self.square = square
        if square:
            self.square.piece = self
        self.movecount += addmovecount
        
    def remove(self):
        return self.placeat(None)

    def moves(self, *movements):
        for target in self.square.targets(self.owner, *self.movements):
            yield Move(Submove(self, target))
      
    def position(self):
        return f"{self}{self.square}"

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.code


class Pawn(Piece):
    code = ""
    movements = ("NE", "NW"), 1, True, True  # Only standard capturing moves are configured here
    
    # Overriding super's to also produce non-capturing pawn moves, promotion, and en-passant
    def moves(self):
        # Forward pawn target square(s):
        targets = list(self.square.targets(self.owner, "N", 1 + (self.square in self.owner.pawnshome), False, False))
        # Capturing squares and en passant target(s):
        enpassantsquares = [player.enpassantsquare for player in self.owner][1:]
        for square in self.square.targets(self.owner, *self.movements[:2]):
            if square.piece or square in enpassantsquares:
                targets.append(square)
        # Construct Move instances for each of those
        for target in targets:
            if not target.S:  # A promotion
                for promotype in (Queen, Rook, Knight, Bishop):
                    yield Move(Submove(self, target, Submove(promotype(self.owner), target)), f"%={promotype.code}")
            elif target in enpassantsquares:  # An en-passant capture
                yield Move(Submove(self, target.N, Submove(self, target)), "%(e.p.)")
            else:  # A forward move, including a 2-step pawn-push 
                yield Move(Submove(self, target), "%", target.S if self.square.N == target.S else None)

class Rook(Piece):
    code = "R"
    movements = ("N", "E", "S", "W"), 10

class Bishop(Piece):
    code = "B"
    movements = ("NE", "SE", "SW", "NW"), 10

class Knight(Piece):
    code = "N"
    movements = ("NNE", "NEE", "SEE", "SSE", "SSW", "SWW", "NWW", "NNW"), 1
        
class Queen(Piece):
    code = "Q"
    movements = Rook.movements[0] + Bishop.movements[0], 10

class King(Piece):
    code = "K"
    movements = Queen.movements[0], 1

    def placeat(self, square, addmovecount=0):
        super().placeat(square, addmovecount)
        if self.owner.king and self.owner.king != self:
            self.owner.king.remove()  # Cannot have more than 1 king
        self.owner.king = square and self  # Track the player's King
        return self

    def moves(self):
        yield from super().moves()
        # Check for castling possibilities
        if self.square == self.owner.kingshome and self.movecount == 0 and not self.square.attackers(self.owner):
            for direction, notation in zip("EW", ("0-0", "0-0-0")):
                rooktarget = getattr(self.square, direction)
                # Is intermediate square free and not attacked?
                if not rooktarget.piece and not rooktarget.attackers(self.owner):
                    target = square = getattr(rooktarget, direction)
                    # Find the rook
                    while not square.piece and getattr(square, direction):
                        square = getattr(square, direction)
                    # Does the king see a rook at the far end which has not moved yet?
                    rook = square.piece
                    if not getattr(square, direction) and type(rook) is Rook and rook.movecount == 0:
                        # We can pseudo castle
                        yield Move(Submove(self, target, Submove(rook, rooktarget)), notation)

                
class Square:
    opposite = {"N": "S", "E": "W", "S": "N", "W": "E"}
    def __init__(self, name, side, down, left):
        # side: Player: Each player has 4 rows of squares in front of them. Side identifies which of
        #    those three groups has this square.
        #    A group's 4 rows are numbered from 0 (nearest to player) to 3 (away from player),
        #    and its 8 half-columns are numbered from left to right from the player's viewpoint.
        # down and left allow to immediately link with neighbors
        self.name = name
        self.side = side
        self.piece = None
        # neighbor references (using direction names as from the closest player's point of view)
        self.N = self.E = None
        self.S = down or None
        self.W = left or None
        # set backreferences
        if down:
            down.N = self
        if left:
            left.E = self

    def clear(self):
        if self.piece:
            self.piece.remove()
            
    def walk(self, path, reverse):  # Yield square(s) at end of relative path
        # Path: string of one or more N, E, S, W (from square's side point of view)
        # Could yield 2 squares if with the reversed order of the directions we arrive at a different square
        prev = None
        for curpath in [path] if path[::-1] == path else [path, path[::-1]]:
            square = self
            curreverse = reverse
            for step in curpath:
                player = square.side
                square = getattr(square, self.opposite[step] if curreverse else step)
                if not square or square is prev:
                    return  # Outside board or same square as in previous iteration
                if square.side != player:
                    curreverse = not curreverse  # Crossed over to different half-board
            yield square, curreverse
            prev = square
        
    # Given constraints about movement, generate target squares that can be reached from this square. 
    def targets(self, player, directions, limit=10, maycapture=True, mustcapture=False):
        reverse = player != self.side  # Whether or not directions should be mirrored
        stack = [(self, reverse, path, limit) for path in directions]
        while stack:  # While there are squares to further expand
            square, reverse, path, limit = stack.pop()
            for square, reverse in square.walk(path, reverse):
                capturing = maycapture and square.piece and square.piece.owner != player
                if capturing or not (mustcapture or square.piece):
                    yield square
                if limit > 1 and not square.piece:  # Continue in the same direction
                    stack.append((square, reverse, path, limit - 1))
                
    def attackers(self, player):  # Returns the other player(s) that have an attack on this field
        attackers = set()
        for Piecetype, Q in ((King, None), (Knight, None), (Pawn, None), (Rook, Queen), (Bishop, Queen)):
            for target in self.targets(player, *Piecetype.movements[:2], True, True):
                if type(target.piece) in (Piecetype, Q):
                    attackers.add(target.piece.owner)
                    if len(attackers) == 2:  # Don't bother looking further...
                        return [player.next, player.next.next]
        return list(attackers)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

@dataclass
class Submove:
    piece: Piece
    target: Square
    next: 'Submove' = None

    def play(self):
        self.source = self.piece.square
        self.captured = self.target.piece 
        self.piece.placeat(self.target, 1)
        if self.next:
            self.next.play()
            
    def undo(self):
        if self.next:
            self.next.undo()
        self.piece.placeat(self.source, -1)
        if self.captured:
            self.captured.placeat(self.target)

class Move:
    def __init__(self, submove, notation="%", enpassantsquare=None):
        self.submove = submove
        player = submove.piece.owner
        self.enpassantsquare = enpassantsquare
        self.play()
        # Get all check givers of all kings:
        checkgivers = [anyplayer.checkgivers() for anyplayer in player]
        self.check = player in checkgivers[1] or player in checkgivers[2]
        self.valid = not (checkgivers[0] or player.next in checkgivers[2])
        # Define the notation of this move
        self.notation = notation.replace("%", f"{submove.piece}{submove.source}{'x-'[not submove.captured]}{submove.next.target if submove.next else submove.target}")
        if self.check:
            self.notation += "+"
        self.undo()

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, Move) and other.notation == self.notation

    def play(self):
        self.submove.play()
                
    def undo(self):
        self.submove.undo()
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.notation

class Player:
    def __init__(self, color, colnames, rownames, next=None):
        self.color = color
        self.next = next or self
        # Create the half-board at the side of this player
        squares = []
        for row, rowname in enumerate(rownames):
            for column, colname in enumerate(colnames):
                square = Square(f"{colname}{rowname}", self, row and squares[-8], column and squares[-1])
                squares.append(square)
        self.squares = squares
        self.kingshome = squares[4]
        self.pawnshome = squares[8:16]
        self.king = self.enpassantsquare = None
        
    def __iter__(self):  # iterate over linked list of players, including self
        side = self
        while True:
            yield side
            side = side.next
            if side == self:
                break
        
    def pieces(self):
        for side in self:
            for square in side.squares:
                if square.piece and square.piece.owner == self:
                    yield square.piece
        
    def add(self, color, colnames, rownames):
        self.next = Player(color, colnames, rownames, self.next)
        # Link cross-group neighbors
        for player in (self, self.next):
            for sq1, sq2 in zip(player.next.squares[:-5:-1], player.squares[-8:]):
                sq1.N = sq2
                sq2.N = sq1
        return self.next

    def position(self):
        return " ".join((piece.position() 
             for piece in sorted(self.pieces(), key=lambda piece: f"{'KQRBNp'.index(piece.code or 'p')}{piece.square}")
        ))

    def moves(self):        
        for piece in self.pieces():
            for move in piece.moves():
                if move.valid:
                    yield move
        
    def checkgivers(self):
        return self.king.square.attackers(self) if self.king else []

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.color

        
class ThreePlayerChess:
    piecetypes = { "p": Pawn, "R": Rook, "N": Knight, "B": Bishop, "K": King, "Q": Queen, "": None }
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):  # red="", white="", black=""
        # Create a linked list of 3 players, each with their half-board of squares
        self.players = { player.color.lower(): player 
                        for player in Player("Red",   "abcdefgh", "1234")
                                        .add("White", "lkjidcba", "8765")
                                        .add("Black", "hgfeijkl", ("12","11","10", "9")).next }
        # Make squares accessible by their names
        self.squaresbyname = { square.name : square
                                for player in self.players.values()
                                for square in player.squares}
        # Set up the pieces at the provided positions (if any)
        self.clear().place(**kwargs)  # red, white, black

    def clear(self):  # Remove all pieces and make white the current player
        self.movelog = []
        self.player = self.players["white"]
        for player in self.players.values():
            for square in player.squares:
                square.clear()
        return self  # to allow chaining

    def place(self, **kwargs):  # red="", white="", black=""
        for color, pieces in kwargs.items():
            player = self.players[color]
            for piece, place in re.findall(r"([A-Z]?)([a-z]\d+)", pieces):
                self.piecetypes[piece or "p"](player).placeat(self.squaresbyname[place])
        return self  # to allow chaining

    def remove(self, pieces):
        for place in re.findall(r"[a-z]\d+", pieces):
            self.squaresbyname[place].clear()
        return self  # to allow chaining

    def startposition(self): # Set up the standard start position 
        self.clear()
        for player in self.players.values():
            for kind, square in zip("RNBQKBNRpppppppp", player.squares):
                self.piecetypes[kind](player).placeat(square)
        return self  # to allow chaining
                    
    def turn(self, playerstr):
        self.player = self.players[playerstr.lower()]
        return self
        
    def moves(self):
        return self.player.moves()
       
    def isincheck(self):
        return bool(self.player.checkgivers())

    def lackofmaterial(self):
        return all(type(piece) == King for player in self.players.values() for piece in player.pieces())
       
    def play(self, movestr):
        if type(movestr) is Move:
            move = (movestr in self.player.moves()) and movestr
        else:
            movestr = movestr.strip()
            move = next((move for move in self.player.moves() if str(move) == movestr), None)
        if not move:
            raise ValueError(f"{movestr} is not a valid move")
        print(f"{self.player} plays {move}")        
        move.play()
        self.movelog.append(move)
        self.player.enpassantsquare = move.enpassantsquare
        self.player = self.player.next
        return self

    def undo(self):
        move = self.movelog.pop()
        self.player = self.player.next.next
        move.undo()
        self.player.enpassantsquare = self.movelog[-1].enpassantsquare if self.movelog else None
        return self
        
    def load(self, text=""):
        self.startposition()
        for movestr in text.strip().split():
            self.play(movestr)
        return self
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return "\n".join(
            f"{player}: {player.position()}"
            for player in self.players.values()
        )


game = ThreePlayerChess().startposition()
# Print all valid moves for White
print(*game.moves())
history = """d7-d5   Nk12-j10  e2-e3
             Nb8-c6  e11-e9    Bf1-b5
             i7-i5   e9xi5     Bb5xc6
             Qi8xc6  Bf12-j9   Ng1-f3
             j7-j5
             """
# Play the above listed moves
game.load(history)
# Print out the location of all pieces on the board
print(game)
print()
# Print all valid moves for White
print(*game.moves())
```

The driver code plays a few moves and prints the position of all the pieces that are on the board, by color.

This is an OOP approach that is useful if the goal is to allow three players to make moves interactively. It is not so useful if you intend to build something that needs to be able to play many moves in a short time, like for performing a tree search in order to evaluate moves. In that latter case, Python would not be the first choice. Using bitmap representations in C++ or C# would be more efficient.

Comment: This is literally perfect. Going through your explanation, I think this may be the best way to implement the board representation. Thank you.

Comment: OK, keep an eye on this answer, as I detected a bug in the `walk` function that I am correcting now.

Comment: And your assumptions about my requirements are exactly correct. I should have stated so in my original post, but I only need something that can handle inputs from players, rather than simulate games of chess quickly or use an AI to evaluate moves. An OOP approach is exactly what I am used to coding with my background in Java.

Comment: OK, I updated the answer now with a bug fix and several other improvements.

Comment: It's gone fine so far. I have been working on the implementation of the GUI with Pygame and have been dealing with how they deal with polygon hitboxes. I really do appreciate the help. I may reach back out soon.

Comment: I have updated the answer with more matured code that now also supports promotion, castling, and en-passant moves.

Answer (score 1):

There are two kinds of data that need to be stored.

- The cell adjacencies so that the board can be traversed using the standard graph theory algorithms.  Any graph theory library can be used for this.
- The piece positions.  I suggest a modified Forsyth–Edwards Notation (FEN) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation  Like this:

It is possible to store the piece position as cell attributes in the board graph.  This is inefficient.  The cell adjacencies are fixed, the piece positions are very dynamic, so it is good to store them separately.  For example, you want to locate the red knight:  If the pieces are stored in the board graph, then you will have to hunt through the 96 cells.  Another example, you want to load a position from a file: you do not need to store the board calls and all their adjacencies, because that never changes, just the piece positions.

Piece placement data: Each rank is described, starting with rank 12 and ending with rank 1, with a "/" between each one; within each rank, the contents of the squares are described in order from the a and ending with h

Each piece is identified by a two letters taken from the standard English names in upper case ( (pawn = "P", knight = "N", bishop = "B", rook = "R", queen = "Q" and king = "K") plus lower case color ( w,b,r ). A set of one or more consecutive empty squares within a rank is denoted by a double digit from "01" to "12", corresponding to the number of squares.

Starting position:

RbNbBbQbKbBbNbRb/PbPbPbPbPbPbPbPb/12/12/RwNwBwQwKwBwNwRw/PwPwPwPwPwPwPwPw/12/12/12/12/PrPrPrPrPrPrPrPr/RrNrBrQrKrBrNrRr

Comment: I could be thinking of the problem incorrectly, but I don't think either case would apply to what I'm building. Since I'm already traversing the graph to locate a valid space depending on the piece occupying a starting position, and I already have a model that shows relative position of every place a piece could be on the board, I think it would make sense to combine the two representations into a single model. The leg work of checking where a piece can move to is already being done, might as well do the operations of moving the piece while you are doing the check.

Comment: Rather than build a second system that seems to effectively accomplish the same thing that would have to be built on top of the graph. I'm not building an AI or anything, so there is no searching the graph for specific pieces, it's only job is to inform valid paths and spaces around a given node based on the piece occupying that space.

Comment: I am just trying to understand how it would slow anything down when the program would already be performing the operations on the graph. I can see that you would want to know the position of the king at any given position.

Answer (score 1):

The three-player chess board consists in three standard half-boards. I would represent it that way: three 4x8 arrays. One array for ABCDEFGHx1234, one array for HGFEIJKLx12,11,10,9, and one array for LKJIDCBAx8765.

- If a piece starts and ends its move in the same half-board, it moves exactly like in chess;
- If a piece starts and ends its move in two different half-boards, it moves as if only these two half-boards existed, ie, if this was regular chess with only these two half-boards making a complete square board.
- If a piece moves through the six squares at the centre, what I said in the previous point might or might not be true depending of your exact rules (I've seen many different rules for three-player chess, especially about how to cross the centre; some of them definitely looked more consistent with the three half-board representation than others).